# Can I override the default rendering of certain graphemes with diacritics?

Tags: unicode, fonts, diacritics, grapheme

I'm looking to add two U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE characters to a Cyrillic letter. When added to Latin letters, the dot diacritics stack, but with Cyrillic letters, the first dot is combined with the letter but the second is rendered to the side, as if it were a standalone grapheme! In Python:

[image]

The same thing occurs in JavaScript, even in the browser:

[image]

Is there a rule that dictates how many diacritics are allowed on a certain base character? Would this be related to font metrics? Or is this effect just a bug? Can it be overridden so that I can see two dots vertically stacked on an э?

Comment: That’s just your font being faulty. Arial and Times New Roman stack the dots correctly, but they still don’t position them right above the letter.

Comment: Great to know! I should have tried a different font.